# How to apply Kubernetes cluster to an existing azure virtual mechines

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have an existing azure virtual machines that deployed 30 docker containers.
So I have decided to use Kubernetes service/cluster to manage deploy dockers container on that existing azure virtual machines.
I have also deploy azure registry to store docker images.

Is it possible way?
Please help to give me your opinion?

Comment: You'll have better luck asking this on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with Ansible then the best way is probably [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray). It is capable of creating clusters almost of any complexity and also contains many features that other cluster management tools like kubeadm don't have.